# React, webpack, and Wavesurfer.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, wavesurfer.js

I am trying to use the npm `react-wavesurfer` package, but get the error

```
this._wavesurfer.init is not a function
```

This seems to be because wavesurfer is not set up properly.  The ["Prereqs and common pitfalls"](https://github.com/mspae/react-wavesurfer#prerequisites-and-common-pitfalls) page on the github states that "WaveSurfer needs to be a globall accessible variable."

```
// provide WaveSurfer as a globally accessible variable
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      WaveSurfer: 'wavesurfer.js'
    })
  ],
  // Alias `wavesurfer` to the correct wavesurfer package.
  // (wavesurfer.js has some non-standard naming convention)
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      wavesurfer: require.resolve('wavesurfer.js')
    }
  },
```

My react project was created with `create-react-app` so I don't have a webpack config file.  **How can I include these wavesurfer plugins?**

**Note:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813585/wavesurfer-js-is-working-fine-but-react-wavesurfer-has-issues) asks the same thing but the only answer is to use the non-react, `wavesurfer.js` package directly.  I would prefer to use `react-wavesurfer`.

Comment: Well it looks like you gotta add custom `webpack.config.js` parameters, which I don't think you can do out of the box in `create-react-app`. If you Google around there's some tools you can use to work around this, but a simpler way might just be to download the relevant `wavesurfer.js` files you need and include them in the `<head/>` of you `index.html`, so they're all loaded before you actual app loads and thus available globally

Comment: Though to be honest, it seems there's been a bunch of changes and new versions since the `react-wavesurfer` stopped being supported, so might not be a bad idea to just use the non-React one